# Нужно с помощью jquery,настроить таблицу что бы при нажатии на checkbox текст менялся на перечеркнутый

Tags: jquery

```html
<tr class="d-flex">
                  <td>
                      <div class="form-check">
                        <label for="" class="form-check-label">
                          <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
                        </label>
                      </div>
                  </td>
                  <td class="table__task__text">
                    <span class="notebookLine1 "></span>
                    <span class="notebookLine2 "></span>
                    <span class="tdLine"></span>
                      Buy a milk
                  </td>
                  <td class="utilites ml-auto">
                      <img src="images/movearrow.png
                      " alt="movearrow">
                      <span class="utilites__lines1"></span>
                      <img src="images/pencil.png" alt="chengetext" >
                      <span class="utilites__lines2"></span>
                      <img src="images/trashbox.png" alt="deletetask">
                  </td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="d-flex">
                  <td>
                      <div class="form-check">
                        <label for="" class="form-check-label">
                          <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
                        </label>
                      </div>
                  </td>
                  <td class="table__task__text">
                    <span class="notebookLine1 "></span>
                    <span class="notebookLine2 "></span>
                    <span class="tdLine"></span>
                      Call Mam
                  </td>
                  <td class="utilites ml-auto">
                      <img src="images/movearrow.png
                      " alt="movearrow">
                      <span class="utilites__lines1"></span>
                      <img src="images/pencil.png" alt="chengetext" >
                      <span class="utilites__lines2"></span>
                      <img src="images/trashbox.png" alt="deletetask">
                  </td>
                </tr>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.form-check-label').each(function(){
        $(this).click(function(){
            $('.table__task__text').toggleClass('line-through')
        })
    })
});
```

что бы для каждой строки в таблице отдельно применялся скрипт,а у меня получилось что ВСЕ строки с текстом меняются при активации checkbox.
Если вы понимаете через че это делать напишите,а дальше сам доделаю.

Comment: и где ваш скрипт?

Comment: уберите `each`, внутри обработчика сначала возьмите `closest('tr')` а у нее уже найдите нужный класс.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Чтобы применялся только в текущей строке надо её и выбирать.

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change',function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').css('text-decoration','line-through');
});
```

Comment: зачем `each`, почему не `closest`, зачем `td`, почему `addClass` ?

Comment: @teran, процитирую автора `Если вы понимаете через че это делать напишите,а дальше сам доделаю.`. Хочу - пишу через `each`, хочу - пишу через `closest`, что мешает мне так делать?

Comment: если вы любите писать бессмысленный код, который может продуцировать ошибки, то пишите.

Comment: @teran, например, какая может быть ошибка?

Comment: если таблица вложенная, то раскрасит обе. а не текущую, т.к. `parents` возвращает всех родителей

Comment: опечатался, там s лишняя

Comment: у меня для вас плохие новости, `parent()` возвращает только непосредственных родителей, в данном случае это `label`, который, очевидно, не пройдет фильтрацию по `tr`

Comment: понял-принял. тупой я, что поделать.. не знал